# Add JSON output to HTML ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to read a JSON file and add the output to HTML IDs. So far everything works, but only as long as I output all IDs afterwards.
However, if I now omit an ID from the output, for example, all the IDs defined below it are no longer output. Why does this happen?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function update_data() {
        $.getJSON("https://example.com/example.json", function(Data) {
                    
            // Example 1
            document.getElementById('example1').innerHTML = Data.example1;
                            
            // Example 2
            document.getElementById('example2').innerHTML = Data.example2;
                    
            // Example 3
            document.getElementById('example3').innerHTML = Data.example3;
        });
    }
update_data();
setInterval(update_data, '30000');
});
```

`https://example.com/example.json` returns something like this in my case:

```
{
    "example1": 725725,
    "example2": 47875,
    "example3": 04257
}
```

If I want to output all 3, it does so. But if I want to output only example1 and example3, it does it only for example1. Why is that?

Does  work:

```
<div id='example1'>Load</div>
<div id='example2'>Load</div>
<div id='example3'>Load</div>
```

Works only for example1:

```
<div id='example1'>Load</div>
<div id='example3'>Load</div>
```

Comment: `But if I want to output only example1 and example3, it does it only for example1` please show us that part of your code, because if i run your code all works fine

Comment: I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8h3dvp2/) to show the problem.

Due to the fact that example2 is not output, example3 is also not output for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: see in your jsfiddle you have error `innerHTML of null..` because example2 is not in your dom .

Comment: Yes. That's exactly where the problem is. 
But why does this happen? 
If I display only example1 and example2 it works. But why can't I display only example1 and example3?

Comment: Because you are provoking a run-time error, that ends your script at that point, where you try to access the innerHTML property of an object that does not really exist at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to test if `id` exists:  test the length for example

```
function update_data() {
    $.getJSON("https://example.com/example.json", function(Data) {
                
        // Example 1
        if($('#example1').length){
           document.getElementById('example1').innerHTML = Data.example1;
         }               
        // Example 2
        if($('#example2').length){                       
            document.getElementById('example2').innerHTML = Data.example2;
        }        
        // Example 3
        if($('#example3').length){
           document.getElementById('example3').innerHTML = Data.example3;
        }
    });
}
```